# using Numba for scipy fsolve, but get error

Tags: python, performance, numba, scipy-optimize, fsolve

I want use numba for scipy.fsolve:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from numba import njit

@njit
def FUN12():
    XGUESS=[8.0,7.0]

    X =[0.0,0.0]
    try:
         X = fsolve(FCN3, XGUESS)
    except:
         print("error")
    return X

@njit
def FCN3(X):
    F=[0.0,0.0]
    F[0]=4.*pow(X[0],2)-3.*pow(X[1],1)-7
    F[1] = 5.*X[0]  -2. * pow(X[1] , 2)+8
    return F

FUN12()
```

I got this error for my code:
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'fsolve': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numba compatible code is only some subset of Python and Numpy functions.

You should not run `fsolve` inside numba function.

You should remove `njit` decorator from FUN12 function. You can keep it for FCN3.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from numba import njit

# @njit  remove this line, 
def FUN12():
    XGUESS=[8.0,7.0]

    X =[0.0,0.0]
    try:
         X = fsolve(FCN3, XGUESS)
    except:
         print("error")
    return X

@njit
def FCN3(X):
    F=[0.0,0.0]
    F[0]=4.*pow(X[0],2)-3.*pow(X[1],1)-7
    F[1] = 5.*X[0]  -2. * pow(X[1] , 2)+8
    return F

FUN12()
```

Comment: Hi dankal444. thank you for your solution. with this edition, it works but it is slower than using Cython. Cython is at least two times faster than this. how I can speed up fslove with Numba?

Comment: @zangmolk ask another question, if you think current one is answered please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can't use `fsolve` itself from within a numba function, there are alternatives that you can use. `fsolve` is a wrapper of the minpack subroutines `hybrd` and `hybrj`, so you can use a numba compatible wrapper of these routines instead. For this, you can use [NumbaMinpack](https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/NumbaMinpack/tree/main) or [cminpack_numba](https://github.com/Nin17/cminpack_numba) (disclaimer I'm the author) which wraps a c translation of minpack instead as in my experience it is faster.

This is how you can solve the given problem with these packages:

```
import cminpack_numba
import NumbaMinpack
from numba import cfunc
import numpy as np

@cfunc(NumbaMinpack.minpack_sig)
def fcn3_numbaminpack(x, fvec, args):
    fvec[0] = 4.*pow(x[0],2)-3.*pow(x[1],1)-7
    fvec[1] = 5.*x[0]  -2. * pow(x[1] , 2)+8
    

@cfunc(cminpack_numba.hybrd_sig)
def fcn3_cminpack_numba(udata, n, x, fvec, iflag):
    fvec[0] = 4.*pow(x[0],2)-3.*pow(x[1],1)-7
    fvec[1] = 5.*x[0]  -2. * pow(x[1] , 2)+8
    return 0

print(FUN12()) # From dankal444's answer
print(NumbaMinpack.hybrd(fcn3_numbaminpack.address, np.array([8.0, 7.0])))
print(cminpack_numba.hybrd1(fcn3_cminpack_numba.address, np.array([8.0, 7.0])))
```

Output:

```
[2. 3.]
(array([2., 3.]), array([5.04476461e-10, 2.50027554e-10]), True, 1)
(array([2., 3.]), array([5.04476461e-10, 2.50027554e-10]), 1)
```

Timings:

```
%timeit FUN12()
%timeit NumbaMinpack.hybrd(fcn3_numbaminpack.address, np.array([8.0, 7.0]))
%timeit cminpack_numba.hybrd1(fcn3_cminpack_numba.address, np.array([8.0, 7.0]))
```

```
14.7 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
3.34 µs ± 40 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
2.68 µs ± 7.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```